# Ramification question in compositum of cyclotomic and degree 5 extension.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields, ramification

I am reviewing some past exam questions and I have a problem solving the following example: Let $F = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5, \sqrt[5]{75})$, a field of degree 20 over $\mathbb{Q}$. Determine the decomposition and inertia groups in $Gal(F/\mathbb{Q})$ for primes in F above $3, 5, 11, 89$. Find the number of primes above $3, 5, 11, 89$ in the subfield $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{75})$, tgether with their ramification and residue degrees over $\mathbb{Q}$.

My attempt: We first check the decomposition of the primes in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{\zeta_5})$, using the Kummer-Dedekind criterion and can completely determine their factorization. My problem lies in checking the factorization in the field above. We could possibly check the how the polynomial $x^5-75$ decomposes modulo those primes and use again the same criterion(even though we would have to know things about the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{75})$).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know, for instance, how the decomposition and inertia groups relate to the correspoding extension of residue fields? How about the Newton polygon? Can you use this, together with the fact that $4$ and $5$ (the degrees of the 2 obvious subextensions) are coprime?

Comment: Well, if we take for example the prime $3$, this is inert in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$, so has residue class degree $4$. We now need to know the residue class degree of $3$, viewed as a prime in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$. This will be $1$ or $5$, as the degree of the intermediate extension is $5$, but I can't see how we can determine that. Maybe we can use Dedekind for $x^5-75$ and say that $3$ is totally ramified there, hence the total residue degree for $F/\mathbb{Q}$ will be $4$?

Comment: Your last remark is what I was hinting at: recall that the ramification index and the residue degree are multiplicative in towers, so you can calculate in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{75})/\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)/\mathbb{Q}$ and then patch them together